# inline R code in yaml block of Rmarkdown file

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, pandoc

Inline R code seems to work well in some fields of yaml block, but not others. For example, this works as expected with an R generated date inserted into the date field:

```
---
title: "docx template"
author: "Dave Braze"
date: '`r format(Sys.time(), "%B %d, %Y")`'
output:
  word_document:
    toc: true
    toc_depth: 2
    highlight: "tango"
    pandoc_args:
    - --reference-docx
    - resources/FDB-styles.docx
    - --output
    - docx-template-20170609.docx
---
```

But this does not, choking on the inline R in the pandoc_args section.

```
---
title: "docx template"
author: "Dave Braze"
date: '`r format(Sys.time(), "%B %d, %Y")`'
output:
  word_document:
    toc: true
    toc_depth: 2
    highlight: "tango"
    pandoc_args:
    - --reference-docx
    - resources/FDB-styles.docx
    - --output
    - '`r paste0("docx-template-", format(Sys.time(), "%Y%m%d"), ".docx")`'
---
```

Here's the error I get:

"C:/PROGRA~2/Pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS docx-template.utf8.md --to docx --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output docx-template.docx --table-of-contents --toc-depth 2 --highlight-style tango --reference-docx resources/FDB-styles.docx --output "`r paste0(\"docx-template-\", format(Sys.time(), \"%Y%m%d\"), \".docx\")`" 
pandoc.exe: `r paste0("docx-template-", format(Sys.time(), "%Y%m%d"), ".docx")`: openBinaryFile: invalid argument (Invalid argument)
Warning: running command '"C:/PROGRA~2/Pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS docx-template.utf8.md --to docx --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output docx-template.docx --table-of-contents --toc-depth 2 --highlight-style tango --reference-docx resources/FDB-styles.docx --output "`r paste0(\"docx-template-\", format(Sys.time(), \"%Y%m%d\"), \".docx\")`"' had status 1
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 1

It seems clear that the second bit of inline R is not being interpreted, but I don't know where to go from here. Any thoughts?

Comment: Yes. Thank you @Yihui-Xi The !expr idiom does work for me: - !expre paste0("docx-template-", format(Sys.time(), "%Y%m%d"), ".docx")

Comment: Did you say `!expre` (note the extra `e`)?

Comment: Aack. It's a typo. Should be: -  !expr paste0("docx-template-", format(Sys.time(), "%Y%m%d"), ".docx")

Comment: Just to make sure, you meant the solution `!expr` worked for you, right?

Comment: Yes. `!expr` works for me.